# Safely move Microsoft SDKs folder

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, directory

I have a folder on my hard drive, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs, and I was wondering if it is safe to move it to an external drive.  Does Visual Studio or any other tool depend on this particular folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a number of entries in the registry (at least in my registry) that point to that location, so it seems *something* would work in a less than optimal fashion.  At a minimum, it would make the uninstaller a bit confused.  It is *probably* safe to simply rename the directory temporarily and try your builds to see if they still work.  Ultimately, though, it seems it would be cleanest to run the installation again to actually remove it and then install to a new location.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Most Unmanaged code in VSStudio refer to certain include files present in the include folder.

Also some exes in bin folder are also referred to (especially VS2008).

VS2005 refers to an internal Platform SDK location.

VS2008 refers to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A

However most projects refer to this location via a macro. So if you can find a way to update the macro with the new location, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this may break some of your applications.  If you added a reference to a project by browsing to a DLL installed in this folder, that project will not compile after you move this folder.  If you haven't added any references in this manner, you might be OK.