# Can I move Windows SDK folder to another volume?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have got plenty of Windows SDKs installed with Visual Studio. The two directories `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs` and `Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits` take a lot of space (approx. 2 GB). Can I move these directories to another volume to reclaim some space on my small SSD C: drive? Can NTFS links to folders or junction points be used to do it? I mean to let it think the files are still in their original places but to place them physically to a different place on a different volume.

Similar question was already asked ( [Safely move Microsoft SDKs folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410149/safely-move-microsoft-sdks-folder) ), but neither NTFS links nor NTFS junction points were discussed there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never tried, but I'd do it the UNIX way - move them and put an NTFS junction (pointing to the new location) in the original position, I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just to confirm Matteo's guess: I've done it using NTFS junction, and works perfectly fine.